# Receptacle flush to the paneling

Tags: electrical

Can the following receptacle be flushed evenly with the paneling or does it have to be extended outward (using an extension depth ring)?[image: Flush or recessed receptacles]? [image]This has been like this for forty years in a couple of locations of the house and if so do i need to change it to be extended beyond the paneling? And if so would a depth extension ring be okay for that purpose or what would you suggest? As it is now, is it  acceptable to NEC standards? Again this was passed when i bought the house. I want to do things right for my house thanks to you guys and gals? In short does the wall plate/receptacle need to be extended out[image] beyond the paneling like this last picture?

Comment: There is nothing to prevent you from recessing it or making it flush.  The reason the cover is typically on the wall instead of in the wall is to hide the hole.  It is hard to make the hole look clean and finished.  The cover plate hides the opening and makes it look neat (and protects the edges of the hole).  Given the large existing hole, you could use an oversized cover to cover it, or molding to serve as a "frame" to neaten it up.

Comment: If you use an oversize cover to cover the hole in the paneling, you will have to shim out the receptacle or it would be springy. If you do this, you "should" use a box extender so that the flammable paneling would be isolated from the contents of the box.

Comment: Any particular box extenders that you can name that would be easy to attached to a metal handy or gang box? I prefer to have it extended.

Comment: I have used two different types, a blue plastic Carlon from HomeDepot and and a softer white plastic type from an electrical supply.  I prefer the latter one for the case where the hole in the wall is too large (what you have), but both can be made to work.  Not exactly this but similiar https://www.amazon.com/Arlington-BE1-5-Electrical-Outlet-Extender/dp/B007EMA6CY?th=1

Comment: Arlington sounds good and is this NEC  ACCEPTABLE with metal outlet? Sorry for being hooked up on NEC-- it is just to ensure that Im in compliance. Again thank you Jin

Comment: The video below says NEC compliant. If you look at youtube videos showing installation of extensions you do **not** have to unhook the wires from the receptacle, but of course you do have to turn off the power at the breaker, completely unscrew the upper and lower screws holding the receptacle in place, and pull the receptacle out . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgWbrfalwjA

Comment: Before you do this you should have in hand the extra large cover plates and check to see that they will cover the extra large rectangle in the paneling and that they fit your receptacle shape. Then you should have a package of the plastic shims because if you use the Arlington extenders, the fins might not be large enough to bridge across the top and bottom gaps and you will need to use shims under the extender box fins to provide a firm physical connection. The top and bottom fins don't need shims if the wall around the box is close but if there is a large gap they need support of shims.

Comment: Here is an alternative to the shims. If the wall is non combustible, then this would be all that one needs. However if the wall material is combustible, then the box extender would be needed on top of this repair ring  as a barrier to prevent a fire in the box from spreading to the wall paneling.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOZZRykKdfM

Comment: Since the outlets look to be on there side is it possible that they are old work boxes? If they are old work boxes they can be adjusted and a oversized cover plate used.

Comment: I like all of the ideas especiallly the simplicitic one of the raco flush fit device leveling plate. Will try your suggestions. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Before you purchase the extenders you should have in hand the extra large cover plates and check to see that they will cover the extra large rectangle in the paneling and that they fit your receptacle shape.

These [extra large extenders](http://www.gordonelectricsupply.com/index~text~5979171~path~product~part~5979171~ds~dept~process~search?gclid=CJqd66j8vdMCFQMGaQod4kUMZw) might be all you need.

But you should have a package of the plastic shims and/or the RACO sheet metal ring support because if you use the Arlington extenders, the fins *might not* be large enough to bridge across the top and bottom gaps and you *might* need to use shims under the extender box fins to provide a firm physical connection. The top and bottom fins don't need shims if the wall around the box is close but if there is a large gap they need support of shims or the RACO sheet metal flush fit device.

[Arlington box extender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgWbrfalwjA)

[sheet metal ring support](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOZZRykKdfM)

Comment: Appreciate the support--will get both and see. Tha k you

Comment: Larry, @larry pinsky, the way you express agreement or thanks on this site is to "upvote" an answer or a comment. Put the mouse pointer on the up arrow on the left and click on it.